# kubernetes Extended resource for pod

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes have a feature named **extended resource**. but I do not know the effects of what it brings.

In other words, what are **the differences** between I use it and I no use it?

Besides, Is the feature similar to **the default limit** or **default request**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended resources are custom resources your nodes can [advertise](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/) to the cluster, to make sure pods scheduled on them are able to have enough of them when scheduling.
The [default limit/request](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/#create-a-limitrange-and-a-pod) allows you to assign these resources implicitly, even if the pod spec did not explicitly specify them.

Comment: So, what is included in the custom resources?

Comment: It's up to you, as you can see in the docs - they use dongle as an example, but it be anything you think of

Comment: Including the CPU limit and memoery limit?

Comment: Cpu and memory are the default resources k8s supports, and are provided by the node exporter.

Comment: @zhangqichuan, if you feel my answer was helpful for you please consider accepting it as the correct answer.